# Can't see the last line after pasted code to snippet editor

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

After I pasted some long codes to the Stack Snippet editor, I couldn't scroll down to the last, "wrapped" line, it's almost invisible:

[image]

Try it in a 800x600 screen, paste this code to the HTML box:

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
    <label for="checkbox1">Tick the check box</label>

    $(function()
    {
        $("#checkbox1").change(function()
        {
            localStorage.check = this.checked;
        });
        var isChecked = localStorage.check ? localStorage.check == "true" : false;
        $("#checkbox1").prop("checked", isChecked);
    });
```

Comment: On which question/answer, link to that?